# Xamarin.UITest find element in [SystemWebView > dom]

Tags: xamarin

In REPL tree I see:

```
tree
[[object CalabashRootView] > DecorView]
  [LinearLayout]
    [FrameLayout] id: "content"
      [SystemWebView > dom] id: "n1"
  [View] id: "navigationBarBackground"
  [View] id: "statusBarBackground"
```

So how can I get elements from dom of the SystemWebView? I see 3 "buttons" but I don't know if the tag of these elements are buttons...
One of them is with name "Home" how can I locate it, spy it?

Best Regards,
Stanislava

Comment: I use xpath with * and it worked: app.Tap(x =>x.XPath("//*[text()='Home']"))

Comment: If you've slove the issue, please post your solution as an answer and mark it. It'll be beneficial for other community members who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use xpath with * and it worked:

```
app.Tap(x =>x.XPath("//*[text()='Home']"))
```